# Error while creating Maven Project in eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, eclipse-juno

I am trying to create a Maven Project using eclipse juno and I am getting errors in below images.

[image: Failed to create project]

[image: Problem occurred]

I have added below maven plugins to my eclipse:
m2e-wro4j
Maven Integration for Eclipse
Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP (Incubation)

I have selected webapp-j2ee14 as an archetype.

Note: The PC I am using is stand alone.

Comment: Have you downloaded all the artifacts needed from Maven Central?

Comment: Yes, I did.
I am getting this error while creating the Maven Project. Once project has been created I am able to clean and install it.

Comment: I normally create it manually outside Eclipse and import it afterwards

Comment: I am new to using Maven, can you please give me the steps to create project manually and than how to import it afterwards to Eclipse ?

Comment: Read maven tutorials first. Install m2e-WTp from the market place to import maven projects.